# try and except code block in python to raise error for missing argument

Tags: python, python-3.x, args, try-except

So I am trying to implement basic try and except logic in my code to read and hand exceptions while reading the command line args:

I have been able to accomplish this. but I want to explicitly say while throwing an error which argument is missing like 1st or 2nd.

Here is my code.

```
import sys
import logging

try:
    job_name = sys.argv[1]
    odate = sys.argv[2]
except IndexError as err:
    print('OS error: {0}'.format(err))
else:
    print('Correct arguments were provided')
```

how could I produce an error to let the user know which arg is missing?

Comment: I would verify that ```sys.argv``` has the proper length before using it, but as a general technique that isn't very sophisticated, you could set ```job_name``` and ```odate``` to ```None``` and check them in the ```except``` block - whichever one is still ```None``` was the cause of the exception.

Comment: If you only receive one argument, there's no way to know which argument is missing. Maybe the user forgot to provide `job_name`. Maybe they forgot to provide `odate`. Maybe they accidentally ran the wrong program entirely and the provided argument wasn't supposed to be either of those arguments. Maybe they *did* provide both arguments, but accidentally hit `b` instead of spacebar and the arguments ended up as one argument.

Comment: Suppose I try to run your program like `foo.py hax`. Did I intend for `hax` to be the job name, or the date? *How can you tell*?

Answer (score 2):

The exception `IndexError` doesn't include the accessed index that resulted to error, you can examine the stack traceback via `traceback.format_exc()` or `sys.exc_info()` or something else just to capture the accessed index but that would be too complicated.

#### Alternative Solution 1

Check first if the length of the arguments is correct and act accordingly:

```
ARG_COUNT = 2
assert len(sys.argv) == ARG_COUNT + 1

# No more need of try-except block
job_name = sys.argv[1]
odate = sys.argv[2]
```

#### Alternative Solution 2

This is the preferable solution. Use [argparse](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#the-add-argument-method) instead. It handles the behavior that you need. You can also customize the settings for each argument further e.g. specifying the expected data type of an argument.

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Process some inputs.')
parser.add_argument('job_name')
parser.add_argument('odate')
args = parser.parse_args()
print(args, args.job_name, args.odate)
```

**Output**

```
$ python script.py 
usage: script.py [-h] job_name odate
script.py: error: the following arguments are required: job_name, odate
$ python script.py some
usage: script.py [-h] job_name odate
script.py: error: the following arguments are required: odate
$ python script.py some thing
Namespace(job_name='some', odate='thing') some thing
```

Comment: Godfrey Pociano for providing the thorough explanation of these alternatives, I am new to python and really appreciate this gesture of yours